# Firefox not showing Bootstrap's CSS transitions

Tags: firefox, css-transitions

I have an issue with Firefox not showing CSS transitions in Bootstrap. It is not only in my own code, Bootstrap's examples (e.g. on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example) are not working in my Firefox. I say 'my Firefox' because I'm confident the problem is my browser config.

## What I tried

- I checked with Chromium ⇒ it works
- I checked on my secondary computer (same Firefox version 70.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04) ⇒ it works
- I created a second user profile in Firefox ⇒ **it does not work**
- I created a second user account ⇒ it works
- I checked an older version of Bootstrap's documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0)/components/collapse/#accordion-example) ⇒ it works (**but not for any version newer than 4.0**)
- I copied the user profile from my second user account over to the primary account ⇒ **it does not work**
- I disabled all add-ons ⇒ **it does not work**
- I restarted Firefox and purged its cache (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache) ⇒ **it does not work**
- I checked the log in the developer tools ⇒ no relevant errors or warnings
- I compared `about:config` with my secondary computer ⇒ no differences for any config item named '*animation*' or '*transition*'
- I checked other CSS transition examples (e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) ⇒ they work
- I completely deleted Firefox' cache directory (`~/.cache/mozilla`) ⇒ **it does not work**

All evidence seems to suggest that the problem is related to my user account, but not to the Firefox user profile. I checked Firefox' config directory (~/.mozilla/firefox). I did not find any non-profile-specific files that could explain this behaviour.

I'm at my wits' end. Any suggestions how to fix Firefox (or what else to check) are highly welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is related to the `prefers-reduced-motion` CSS media feature.

These 2 files contain some of the related code:

```
bootstrap/scss/mixins/_transition.scss
bootstrap/scss/_transitions.scss
```

I was experiencing the same issue on Windows 7 and found this article:
[prefers-reduced-motion - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion)

Here's a snippet from the link:

> ### User Preferences
>
> ## For Firefox, the reduce request is honoured if:
>
> - In GTK/Gnome, if gtk-enable-animations is set to false. This is configurable via GNOME Tweaks (Appearance tab or General tab, depending on version).
>
>   - Alternately, add gtk-enable-animations = false to the [Settings] block of the GTK 3 configuration file.
> - In Windows 10: Settings > Ease of Access > Display > Show animations in Windows.
> - In Window 7: Control Panel > Ease of Access > Make the computer easier to see > Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible).
> - In macOS: System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Reduce motion.
> - In iOS: Settings > General > Accessibility > Reduce Motion.
> - In Android 9+: Settings > Accessibility > Remove animations.